# Cannot access doc['field'].value in ElasticSearch aggregation script

Tags: elasticsearch

With the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": [],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "fields": [
                  "title"
                ],
                "query": "test"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_field": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my_field.name.raw",
        "script": "doc['title'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> QueryPhaseExecutionException[[index_name][2]: query[title:test],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: PropertyAccessException[[Error: doc['title'].value: null] [Near : {... doc['title'].value ....}] ^ [Line: 1, Column: 1]]; nested: InvocationTargetException; nested: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;

I also try using `_source.title`, `doc.get('title').value`, and other combinations of the `doc['field']` syntax - none are working for me. Is there a special nuance for using `script` within an aggregation? Am I missing something obvious?

This fails on both ES 1.1.1 and 1.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I can answer my own question. From [the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_values_source):

> When both field and script settings are configured for the aggregation, the script will be treated as a value script. While normal scripts are evaluated on a document level (i.e. the script has access to all the data associated with the document), value scripts are evaluated on the value level. In this mode, the values are extracted from the configured field and the script is used to apply a "transformation" over these value/s.

I was specifying a "field" param, meaning I was dealing with a value script.

I also [asked this question on the ES Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/elasticsearch/k1uq2z5Uox0), and provided the same feedback there.

Comment: Hi, How did you solve this problem? the links are not working.

Comment: I don't recall, this was from a long time ago. This applied to versions 1.1.1 and 1.2.0 of ES, I am not sure how this might apply in the context of more recent and supported versions.